how to display the time of posts in wordpress in post single page ? (theme publisher)
I have WordPress using the Publisher theme (Newspaper). In a single post, I have the name of the publisher and the date of the post, for example, "by: Jack published: 11/11/2024", but I don't have the time. How can I display the time of the post?
When I go to the dashboard of WordPress settings, I update the date format and add the time, but nothing changes.
SCREENSHOT here 
